# Como criar um Gif com o conteudo do Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Gostaria de saber como criar um gif a partir de um canvas, nesse meu canvas eu tenho uma seguencia de cenas, depois das cenas serem criadas queria ler todas as cenas e depois salvar elas como um .gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O canvas não permite tal operação nativamente, vai precisar de uma biblioteca externa para conseguir criar um GIF.

Experimente [jsgif](https://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif)

Exemplo de uso (extraído do github):

```
var encoder = new GIFEncoder();
  encoder.setRepeat(0); //0  -> loop forever
                        //1+ -> loop n times then stop
  encoder.setDelay(500); //go to next frame every n milliseconds
  encoder.start();
  encoder.addFrame(context);
  encoder.finish();
  var binary_gif = encoder.stream().getData();
  var data_url = 'data:image/gif;base64,'+encode64(binary_gif);
```